# Bitmap to PrinterDocument page resolution is not matching

Tags: c#, printing, graphics, bitmap, dpi

The problem I am having is getting the new Bitmap to sync properly with the size of the printer output using `DrawImageUnscaled()` inside the `PrinterDocument`'s `PrintPage` event.

I got the idea to render an image as a page collection from the comments on another post where I asked how to work with the printer in a more traditional style ( `NewPage`, drawing items *before* calling `Print`, etc  ) which does not exist within the .NET framework. On my first attempt to use an Image collection, I noticed their was some graininess when using `.DrawImage()` even after setting the Bitmap Dpi to the same Dpi as the printer object, which I found was discoverable without printing using the `PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics()` Graphics object through trial and error (lots of error.

The result of this endeavor thus far, is the following class (it has some 'test' code where I have been playing around, but I have cleaned up most of it so it is more presentable here)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

using PdfFileWriter;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.ComponentModel;

using System.IO;

class PDF : PrintDocument {
    /// <summary>
    /// Logo to display on invoice
    /// </summary>
    public Image Logo { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current X position on canvas
    /// </summary>
    public int X { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current Y position on canvas
    /// </summary>
    public int Y { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the folder where backups, downloads, etc will be stored or retrieved from
    /// </summary>
    [Editor( typeof( System.Windows.Forms.Design.FolderNameEditor ), typeof( System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor ) )]
    public string Folder { get { return directory; } set { directory=value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current font used to print
    /// </summary>
    public Font Font { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current font color
    /// </summary>
    public Color ForeColor { get; set; }

    private int CurrentPagePrinting { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set printer margins
    /// </summary>
    public Margins PrintMargins {
        get { return DefaultPageSettings.Margins; }
        set { DefaultPageSettings.Margins = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pages drawn in document
    /// </summary>
    private List<Image> Pages;

    /// <summary>
    /// The current selected page number. 0 if nothing selected
    /// </summary>
    private int CurrentPage;

    /// <summary>
    /// The current working directory to save files to
    /// </summary>
    private string directory;

    /// <summary>
    /// The currently chosen filename
    /// </summary>
    private string file;

    /// <summary>
    /// Public acceisble object to all paperSizes as set
    /// </summary>
    public List<PrintPaperSize> paperSizes { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Object for holding papersizes
    /// </summary>
    public class PrintPaperSize {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Width { get; set; }

        public PrintPaperSize() {
            Height = 0;
            Width = 0;
            Name = "";
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current papersize selected. used for some calculations
    /// </summary>
    public PrintPaperSize CurrentPaperSize { get; private set; }

    public PDF() {
        // set the file name without extension to something safe
        file = (string)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds.ToString();

        // set the save directory to MyDocuments
        directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        CurrentPage = 0;

        // initialize pages array
        Pages = new List<Image>();

        // Set the initial font and color
        Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", (float)11.25);
        ForeColor = Color.Black;

        // set the printer to Microsoft's PDF printer and generate and ensure it will save to a file
        PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings() {
            PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",
            PrintToFile = true,
            PrintFileName = Path.Combine(directory, file + ".pdf"),
        };

        // hide the notice 'printing' while spooling job.
        PrintController = new StandardPrintController();

        // set the printer quality to maximum so we can use this for getting the dpi at this setting
        DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.Kind = PrinterResolutionKind.High;

        // store all paper sizes at 1 dpi [ reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/05169a47-04d5-4890-9b0a-7ad11a6a87f2/need-pixel-width-for-paper-sizes-a4-a5-executive-letter-legal-executive?forum=csharpgeneral ]
        paperSizes = new List<PrintPaperSize>();
        foreach ( PaperSize P in PrinterSettings.PaperSizes ) {
            double W=P.Width/100.0;
            double H=P.Height/100.0;

            paperSizes.Add(
                new PrintPaperSize() {
                    Height = H,
                    Width = W,
                    Name = P.PaperName
                }
            );

            if ( P.PaperName=="Letter" ) {
                CurrentPaperSize = paperSizes[paperSizes.Count-1];
            }
        }

        // setup the initial page type, orientation, margins, 
        using ( Graphics g=PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics() ) {
            DefaultPageSettings = new PageSettings(PrinterSettings) {
                PaperSize=new PaperSize( CurrentPaperSize.Name, (Int32)(CurrentPaperSize.Width*g.DpiX), (Int32)(CurrentPaperSize.Height*g.DpiY) ),
                Landscape = false,
                Margins = new Margins(left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                PrinterResolution=new PrinterResolution() {
                    Kind = PrinterResolutionKind.High
                }
            };
        }

        // constrain print within margins
        OriginAtMargins = true;
    }


    public void SetPaperSize( PaperKind paperSize ) {
        // TODO: Use Linq on 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get specific page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="page">page number. 1 based array</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Image GetPage( int page ) {
        int p = page - 1;
        if ( p<0||p>Pages.Count ) { return null; }
        return Pages[p];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the current page
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Image</returns>
     public Image GetCurrentPage() {
        return GetPage(CurrentPage);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Before printing starts
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">PrintEventArgs</param>
    protected override void OnBeginPrint( PrintEventArgs e ) {
         CurrentPagePrinting=0;
         base.OnBeginPrint( e );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Print page event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">PrintPageEventArgs</param>
    protected override void OnPrintPage( PrintPageEventArgs e ) {
        CurrentPagePrinting++;

        // if page count is max exit print routine
        if ( CurrentPagePrinting>=Pages.Count ) { e.HasMorePages=false; base.OnPrintPage( e ); return; }

        // ensure high resolution / clarity of image so text doesn't fuzz
        e.Graphics.CompositingMode=CompositingMode.SourceOver;
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality=CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        // Draw image and respect margins (unscaled in addition to the above so text doesn't fuzz)
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(
            Pages[CurrentPagePrinting-1],
            new Point(
                DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top,
                DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
            )
        );
        base.OnPrintPage( e );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// After printing has been completed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">PrintEventArgs</param>
    protected override void OnEndPrint( PrintEventArgs e ) {
        base.OnEndPrint( e );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new page to the document
    /// </summary>
    public void NewPage() {
        // Add a new page to the page collection and set it as the current page

        Bitmap bmp;
        using(Graphics g = PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics()) {
            float dpiscaleX;
            float dpiscaleY;

            // measure default bitmap dpi on this system and use to calculate print dpi
            using ( Bitmap b=new Bitmap( 1, 1 ) ) {
                dpiscaleX = b.HorizontalResolution;
                dpiscaleY = b.VerticalResolution;
            };

            bmp = new Bitmap( 
                (Int32)(((DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width-( DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left+DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right )) / dpiscaleX) * g.DpiX),
                (Int32)(((DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height-( DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top+DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom )) / dpiscaleY) * g.DpiY)
            );
            bmp.SetResolution(g.DpiX, g.DpiY);
        }
        Pages.Add( bmp );
        CurrentPage++;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new string to the current page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The string to print</param>
    /// <param name="align">Optional alignment of the string</param>
    public void DrawString(string text, System.Windows.TextAlignment align = System.Windows.TextAlignment.Left ) {
        // add string to document
        using ( Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage( Pages[CurrentPage - 1] ) ) {
            g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            switch ( align ) {
                case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Left:
                case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Justify:
                    g.DrawString( text, Font, new SolidBrush( ForeColor ), new PointF( X, Y ) );
                    Y+=(Int32)g.MeasureString( "X", Font ).Height;
                    break;
                case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Right:
                    g.DrawString( text, Font, new SolidBrush( ForeColor ), new PointF( Pages[CurrentPage - 1].Width - g.MeasureString( text, Font ).Width, Y ) );
                    Y += (Int32)g.MeasureString( "X", Font ).Height;
                    break;
                case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center:
                    g.DrawString( text, Font, new SolidBrush( ForeColor ), new PointF( ( Pages[CurrentPage-1].Width+g.MeasureString( text, Font ).Width )/2, Y ) );
                    Y+=(Int32)g.MeasureString( "X", Font ).Height;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Illustration of PDF output

[image: Demonstration of Dpi]

As you can see, the canvas (`Page` property in my class), goes out of bounds. If I draw the image using just `.DrawImage()` the scaling stretches it and it just looks grainy, so I must use `.DrawImageUnscaled()`

The lines above in order are the result of the following code :

```
// Initialize the custom print class
PDF p = new PDF();

// Add a new page to the document
p.NewPage();

// Draw some strings.  p.Y value is automatically incremented
p.DrawString( "Hello" );
p.DrawString( "Hello", System.Windows.TextAlignment.Right );
p.DrawString( "Hello", System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center );
p.DrawString( "Hello pure awesomeness" );

// Uncomment the following and add a picture box to the form
// pictureBox1.Height = 1100;
// pictureBox1.Width = 850;
// pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
// pictureBox1.Image = p.GetCurrentPage();

// Send all pages to the "printer"
p.Print();
```

If you uncomment the `pictureBox1` lines, and comment out `p.Print()`, the result is correct (keeping in mind the image is smaller than the printdocument page due to the margins being set for the page.

## Illustration of PictureBox output

[image: Demonstration of Dpi in PictureBox]

And if you use the following code (in place of the above `pictureBox` code) which is functionally equivalent to the Dpi scaling inside the class, everything shows up properly in the `pictureBox` (just a lot larger as my 'High' setting resolves to 600 DPI where a newly created Bitmap is at 72 DPI before calling the `SetResolution()` method on the Image.

```
Image img = p.GetCurrentPage();

pictureBox1.Height=(Int32)(p.CurrentPaperSize.Height*img.VerticalResolution);
pictureBox1.Width = (Int32)(p.CurrentPaperSize.Width*img.HorizontalResolution);
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

Comment: Use WPF printing, WinForms usually have problems with DPI. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WPF-Printing-Overview-f28c541a#content

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal - thank you, however that was not the problem. I had an issue with how I was calculating the margins.  The printersettings margin is in 100ths of an inch, and I was only taking that value into account as the 'whole' margin. Now to add an event for when a new page is automatically added, and allow user control to print stuff to it before printing the next line (also allow the user to change the X / Y position inside the event. (great for handling full header / etc). Will post my findings as a solution for others :)

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal - solution posted :)

Answer (score 0):

The calculation for measuring `DefaultPageSettings.Margins` was wrong as `Margins` are represented in 100th's of an inch [according to this MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.margins(v=vs.110).aspx). The correct way to adjust for this is to divide by 100.

```
x = DefaultPageSettings.Margins/100
```

Following is the OP's `NewPage()` method rewritten with the proper calculations :

```
/// <summary>
/// Add a new page to the document
/// </summary>
public void NewPage() {
    // Add a new page to the page collection and set it as the current page

    Bitmap bmp;
    using(Graphics g = PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics()) {
        int w=(Int32)( CurrentPaperSize.Width*g.DpiX )-(Int32)( ( ( DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left+DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right )/100 )*g.DpiX );
        int h=(Int32)( CurrentPaperSize.Height*g.DpiY )-(Int32)( ( ( DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top+DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom )/100 )*g.DpiY );
        bmp = new Bitmap( w, h );
        bmp.SetResolution(g.DpiX, g.DpiY);
    }

    // reset X and Y positions
    Y=0;
    X=0;

    // Add new page to the collection
    Pages.Add( bmp );
    CurrentPage++;
}
```